# How to refer to someone without specialist knowledge in an academic journal paper

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, academia

I'm writing a journal paper and I want to find a suitable way to refer to someone who lacks formal training in a specialist field or specialist knowledge. The only example I can think of so far is "layperson". [Checking this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319354/whats-a-word-for-someone-with-low-level-of-knowledge-in-an-area-and-no-intenti) it seems these suggestions are unsuitable for academic style.  My specific usage example is as follows:

"For the operator, the extremes of suitable clinical training as opposed to '__________' will be considered."

However, I have had this problem before and would appreciate alternatives that may be a more general solution than for the specific usage above. Along with suitable academic style, another issue I'm specifically trying to avoid is being disrespectful towards the person/group I'm referring to.

Comment: Is it supposed to be a noun or an adjective?

Comment: I believe a noun would be most suitable. Similar in the way "dilettante" might be used.

Comment: Why would you need specialist knowledge just to refer to someone? (/joking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone trained in another part of a broad field may be described as *non-specialist*, which can still imply quite a high level of training. This is used for scientific instruments pitched at a user who is interested in the results rather than the mechanism by which they are obtained.

*Lay* as an adjective opens up possibilities not covered by "layperson" . It can be used as "lay reader" or "lay user"  for example, giving an idea of the role. This could even be considered more respectful as "layperson", which is too close a synonym for "amateur" in some contexts.

It's often best though to be as specific as possible. You might refer to *a user with basic first aid training* or *an untrained user* (if for example you're discussing a defibrillator).

Comment: I think in my specific case "non-specialist" will likely work the best. I did like vickyace's suggestion of rudiments but felt that it may give an impression of talking down about the group. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [rudiment](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rudiment) (usually used in plural)

> A basic principle or element or a fundamental skill
>
> something unformed and undeveloped: **beginning**

Also, [a definition from oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/rudiments)

> basic principles, basics, fundamentals, elements, essentials, first principles,

Beginnings, foundation, **basic skills**

"For the operator, the extremes of suitable clinical training as opposed to 'rudiments' will be considered."